# how to get all JPA objects for a list of IDs, or how to make a JPA query out of this SQL query?

Tags: sql, jpa

I have a Project that has many Tasks.

I have a SQL query that returns all the projectIds for a userId by querying the TASKS table ... here it is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(projectId) 
FROM TASKS
WHERE userId = '55' AND status = 'IN_PROGRESS';
```

First, I'm wondering is there an easy JPA way to get all the Project objects given the list of project ids?

Second, how can I make a JPA query that does what this SQL does?  I'm guessing it would have to be something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Project p)
WHERE /*one of the tasks*/ p.tasks[].userId = '55' AND p.tasks[].status = 'IN_PROGRESS';
```

But I have no idea.  Any suggestions are GREATLY appreciated!

Rob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I'm wondering is there an easy JPA way to get all the Project objects given the list of project ids*

```
select p from Project p where p.id in :projectIds
```

*how can I make a JPA query that does what this SQL does?*

```
select distinct project.id 
from Task task
inner join task.project project
where task.userId = :userId and task.status = :status;
```

Read documentation about JPQL, because this is pretty basic stuff. Here's the [Hibernate documentation on HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql), which is a small superset of JPQL.